# Keyboard shortcut to execute a shell command in iTerm2

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings, iterm2, keymapping

Say in my repo I tend to frequently do `open .` or `open .gitignore` from the command line. I'd like to have keyboard shortcuts for iTerm2 that just do these two.

Comment: Did you maybe find out how to do it?

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way to do it:

In *Preferences › Keys › Key Bindings*, add a new key binding with these values:

- Shortcut of your choosing
- Action: `Send Text`
- With value:

```
open .gitignore
```

Mind the line-break (you can add it with option-Enter) so as to execute the command and not just paste it.

(I use this with Cmd-S as a shortcut to `git status`.)